# Question about a unique primary key vs unique primary index

Tags: teradata

I searched many different topics here on stack over flow related to this question, but I can't seem to find an answer that makes sense to me. I come from a  MS SQL Server background where just about every table has a primary key and many more have foreign keys. In Teradata I understand there are Primary keys and also unique primary indexes. It is to my understanding that values for a unique primary index in Teradata can't be null. If that is the case why even use primary keys at all? Is it just to enforce parent child relationships in the table structures like other RDBMS systems such as a sales order header table (PK) and sales order detail table (fk)? Maybe a good use for a UPI without a PK would be a table that has no relationships to another table like a "reporting" table?

Just want to make sure I understand correctly. Thank you for the help.

Comment: In Teradata, a primary index is only used for distribution of the data.  It has nothing to with a PK.  [A little light reading](https://www.docs.teradata.com/r/xrmOxQlXa0ETFi5lPxHJaQ/BjKc7IiGbDx24wBEmnbgpA)

Comment: The `PRIMARY KEY` columns must be `NOT NULL`, but `UNIQUE PRIMARY INDEX` columns can be` NULL` (in which case, NULL is treated as a single, distinct value for purpose of determining uniqueness).

Comment: Teradata allows you to have nulls in your UPI, but that doesn't make it a very good idea...